# Why a byte buffer from CGO can reads correctly but write fault?

Tags: go, cgo

I am using this library https://github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse, and some interfaces need to be implemented，one of them looks like this:

```golang
func (self *Memfs) Write(path string, buff []byte, ofst int64, fh uint64) (n int) {
    defer trace(path, buff, ofst, fh)(&n)
    defer self.synchronize()()
    node := self.getNode(path, fh)
    if nil == node {
        return -fuse.ENOENT
    }
    endofst := ofst + int64(len(buff))
    if endofst > node.stat.Size {
        node.data = resize(node.data, endofst, true)
        node.stat.Size = endofst
    }

    fmt.Println("len(buff) = ", len(buff))  // (1)
    fmt.Println("cap(buff) = ", cap(buff))  // (2)
    fmt.Println("buff[0] = ", buff[0])      // (3)
    buff[0] = 1                             // (4)

    n = copy(node.data[ofst:endofst], buff)
    tmsp := fuse.Now()
    node.stat.Ctim = tmsp
    node.stat.Mtim = tmsp
    return
}
```

This is a file system, Write is called when writing to a file. I added (1), (2), (3), (4) in the above code, but it was wrong at (4).  The error stack is as follows：

```golang
unexpected fault address 0x116e6c60390
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x116e6c60390 pc=0xca7dad]

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw(0xcf373f, 0x5)
    D:/Scoop/apps/go/current/src/runtime/panic.go:1117 +0x79 fp=0xc000033bc8 sp=0xc000033b98 pc=0xc18db9
runtime.sigpanic()
    D:/Scoop/apps/go/current/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:245 +0x2d6 fp=0xc000033c20 sp=0xc000033bc8 pc=0xc2b7d6
main.(*Memfs).Write(0xc00001e400, 0xc00000a2b0, 0x9, 0x116e6c60390, 0x40000, 0x40000000, 0x0, 0x2, 0x9)
    D:/code/go/LiangFs/tool/memfs.go:310 +0x4cd fp=0xc000033de0 sp=0xc000033c20 pc=0xca7dad
github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse/fuse.hostWrite(0x116e00d1480, 0x116e6c60390, 0x40000, 0x0, 0x1518fff7c8, 0x0)
    D:/go/pkg/mod/github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse@v1.5.0/fuse/host.go:255 +0x102 fp=0xc000033e60 sp=0xc000033de0 pc=0xc9c282
github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse/fuse.go_hostWrite(...)
    D:/go/pkg/mod/github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse@v1.5.0/fuse/host_cgo.go:911
_cgoexp_12ef5be0dd8c_go_hostWrite(0x1518fff710)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:738 +0x59 fp=0xc000033ea0 sp=0xc000033e60 pc=0xca2919
runtime.cgocallbackg1(0xca28c0, 0x1518fff710, 0x0)
    D:/Scoop/apps/go/current/src/runtime/cgocall.go:292 +0x19a fp=0xc000033f40 sp=0xc000033ea0 pc=0xbe4c5a
runtime.cgocallbackg(0xca28c0, 0x1518fff710, 0x0)
    D:/Scoop/apps/go/current/src/runtime/cgocall.go:228 +0xfc fp=0xc000033fb8 sp=0xc000033f40 pc=0xbe49bc
runtime.cgocallback(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    D:/Scoop/apps/go/current/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:788 +0xc0 fp=0xc000033fe0 sp=0xc000033fb8 pc=0xc48bc0
runtime.goexit()
    D:/Scoop/apps/go/current/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371 +0x1 fp=0xc000033fe8 sp=0xc000033fe0 pc=0xc48ea1

goroutine 1 [syscall]:
github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse/fuse._Cfunc_hostMount(0x3, 0xc00001e420, 0x116e0316540, 0x0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:502 +0x4f
github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse/fuse.c_hostMount.func1(0xc000000003, 0xc00001e420, 0x116e0316540, 0x116e0316540)
    D:/go/pkg/mod/github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse@v1.5.0/fuse/host_cgo.go:820 +0x8c
github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse/fuse.c_hostMount(0xc000000003, 0xc00001e420, 0x116e0316540, 0xb)
    D:/go/pkg/mod/github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse@v1.5.0/fuse/host_cgo.go:820 +0x45
github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse/fuse.(*FileSystemHost).Mount(0xc00003e040, 0xcf4632, 0xb, 0xc000034210, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1ffffff00)
    D:/go/pkg/mod/github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse@v1.5.0/fuse/host.go:704 +0x413
main.main()
    D:/code/go/LiangFs/tool/memfs.go:594 +0xce
len(buff) =  262144
cap(buff) =  1073741824
buff[0] =  97
```

the content of buff is all 97, becasue I copy the following file to this file system:
[image]

The code comes from the example in the library https://github.com/billziss-gh/cgofuse/blob/master/examples/memfs/memfs.go , I just added the (1), (2), (3), (4) mentioned above.

My os is windows 10,  go version is go1.16.7 windows/amd64.

Why does assigning a slice element make a mistake? Is it because the library uses CGO?

Comment: can you share the shap of the byte slice ? len / cap / content ? I would rename this to `fault writing to a byte buffer received from cgo`, but i am unsure where that buffer comes from really. Also, add your `go version`. and your os details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added some new infomation to the questions

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of both WinFsp and cgofuse and can explain what is happening here.

The buffer that you receive in `Write` should always be treated as a read-only buffer. Attempting to write into this buffer may result in an access violation. This is by design.

When an application issues a `WriteFile` request, the WinFsp kernel mode driver has to somehow transfer the data from the application to the user mode file system. The driver has a few different strategies for doing so and under certain circumstances it will choose a zero-copy technique: it will map the application buffer directly into the address space of the user mode file system, thus avoiding an expensive memory copy.

In the case of `Write` this zero-copy mapping will always be read-only in order to avoid the case where a user mode accidentally or maliciously writes into an application's `WriteFile` buffer. (Also note that when the WinFsp driver sets up this mapping, it does so in a way that ensures that there is no accidental data leakage from the application into the user mode file system either.)

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing is printed *after* `buf[0] = 1 // (4)`, we don't know wether the panic comes from this line of code or a line afterwards ; you have to debug further to spot where the bug lies.

Actually : the stack trace you pasted mentions `LiangFs/tool/memfs.go:310`.
If this line number refers to the file you linked to, this line is the `return` instruction in your `.Write()` function.

The error must be triggered by one of the two `defer` calls (which get executed when you return from your function).